# Elasticsearch: all prefixes must appear in a document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am using `match_phrase_prefix` but I want all the words in a query to be treated as prefixes, and these prefixes must appear in a document, regardless of order. Extra tokens in a document are fine.

For example, the search  **Nik shoe Mic Jord** should match:

1. **Nik**e **shoe**s are worn by **Mic**hael **Jord**an
2. **Mic**hael **Jord**an wears **shoe**s from **Nik**e

However, the following should not match:

1. Mike Jordan (*because only the prefix Jord is present*)
2. Nike is owned by Michael Jordan (*because the prefix shoe is missing*)

So the questions are: how can I treat all words as prefixes, and how can I ensure that all prefixes appear in a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the solution, given by @jaspreet would work, but it requires creating edge n-gram tokens, and apart from finding the right balance of `min and max ngram`, it could create huge index size, for a small fraction of queries and **cause performance issues and changing this setting again and again would require re-indexing.**

Another solution for this is to use [the prefix queries, specially created for such use-cases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) as shown in the following example, with just one caveat, as you are using the case-sensitive search(you should ideally lowercase all the search terms to make it case-insensitive search and its a best practice as well.)

### Simple index Def

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Index all 4 sample docs

```
{
  "title" : "Nike shoes are worn by Michael Jordan"
}


{
  "title" : "Michael Jordan wears shoes from Nike"
}

{
  "title" : "Mike Jordan"
}

{
  "title" : "Nike is owned by Michael Jordan"
}
```

### Prefix search query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "nik"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "shoe"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "mic"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "title": {
                            "value": "jord"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### And your expected result

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "prefix",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 4.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Nike shoes are worn by Michael Jordan"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "prefix",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 4.0,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Michael Jordan wears shoes from Nike"
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html)

> Returns documents that contain the words of a provided text, in the
>   same order as provided. The last term of the provided text is treated
>   as a prefix, matching any words that begin with that term.

So "Nik shoe Mic Jord" will do phrase search for Jord only and tokens must also appear in same order.

For phrase search on all tokens use [edge n gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

> The edge_ngram tokenizer first breaks text down into words whenever it encounters one of a list of specified characters, then it emits N-grams of each word where the start of the N-gram is anchored to the beginning of the word.

Mapping

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,  --> size of tokens
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
       "title":{
         "type": "text",
         "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Docs:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "index80",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6RTKTXEBLqTvxU9z8bl3",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Nike shoes are worn by Michael Jordan"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index80",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6hTLTXEBLqTvxU9zIrks",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Michael Jordan wears shoes from Nike"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index80",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6xTLTXEBLqTvxU9zQbm4",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Mike Jordan"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index80",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "7BTLTXEBLqTvxU9zbLkT",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Nike is owned by Michael Jordan"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "Nik shoe Mic Jord",
        "operator": "and"  --> all tokens are needed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
[
      {
        "_index" : "index80",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6RTKTXEBLqTvxU9z8bl3",
        "_score" : 3.2434955,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Nike shoes are worn by Michael Jordan"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index80",
         "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "6hTLTXEBLqTvxU9zIrks",
        "_score" : 3.1820722,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Michael Jordan wears shoes from Nike"
        }
      }
    ]
```

For word "michael" with min-gram:2 and max-gram:5 following tokens are generated

```
{
      "token" : "Mi",
      "start_offset" : 23,
      "end_offset" : 25,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 13
    },
    {
      "token" : "Mic",
      "start_offset" : 23,
      "end_offset" : 26,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 14
    },
    {
      "token" : "Mich",
      "start_offset" : 23,
      "end_offset" : 27,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 15
    },
    {
      "token" : "Micha",
      "start_offset" : 23,
      "end_offset" : 28,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 16
    },
    {
      "token" : "Michae",
      "start_offset" : 23,
      "end_offset" : 29,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 17
    },
    {
      "token" : "Michael",
      "start_offset" : 23,
      "end_offset" : 30,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 18
    }
```

token size of of 2 to 5 words so choice of min and max gram is important. Large difference will cause your index to bloat and small difference can lead to documents not matching

Comment: While this would work, but has some disadvantages as mentioned in my below answer, also one another major disadvantage is **not having the case-insensitive search as you are not using the `lowercase` filter**

Comment: Interesting implementation didn't think of it :)